# In java, is it possible to add the Serializable interface to class that doesn't have it at runtime?

Tags: java, serialization

There is a class I want to serialize, and it implements Serializable, but one of the objects it contains does not implement Serializable.

Is there a way to modify the class at runtime to make it implement the Serializable interface so I can serialize it?  I can't change it at compile time because its a third party library.

Maybe I would have to use some sort of bytecode writer or something?

EDIT: Both the containing class and contained class are in the 3rd party library so I don't think i can mark something as transient.  The containing class *is* marked as serializable, but it contains an object that is not.

I'm fine with writing a custom serialization method for the class, not sure how I would do this though, would I have to use reflection to get the values of the private variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the javadoc for Serializable, I see:

> Classes that require special handling
>   during the serialization and
>   deserialization process must implement
>   special methods with these exact
>   signatures:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
     throws IOException
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
 private void readObjectNoData() 
     throws ObjectStreamException;
```

which you could use to manually serialize the uncooperative fields. You could look into using ASM, but it seems hard to believe that it is a maintainable solution.

Comment: Use Externalizable interface http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html

Comment: The containing class is also in the 3rd party library so I don't think I could add those methods to it.

Answer (score 3):

Fields can be skipped using the `transient` modifier. Additional data can be added to the stream by providing `readObject` and `writeObject` methods. Classes can be subclassed to make them serialisable (though you will need to manage the superclass data), or use a serial proxy (see Effective Java).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you *really* need to do this? Maybe the class in the third-party library is not serializable by design. Even if it's just an omission rather than a deliberate decision, it's easy enough to write a custom serialization method in a helper class. If you *have* to do this though (like I had to, for something similar). Take a look at [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). You can do something like this:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc = pool.get("mypackage.MyClass");
cc.addInterface(pool.get("java.io.Serializable"))
```

EDIT: You can use a third-party Serialization API like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) instead of doing all the dirty work yourself.

Comment: About writing the custom serialization method in a helper class: How would I do this?  Do I need to use reflection to get the private variable values?

Comment: LOL. This answer is _already_ the third Google result for "serialization java third party" 32 minutes after the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

If a class is not marked as Serializable that might be of good reasons (take database connections as an example). So first of all make your self clear if you really need to serialize that object as well. If you just need to serialize the surrounding object you may consider marking the contained object as transient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.lang.reflect.Proxy to add the Serializable interface to object instances over which you have no life-cycle control (i.e. can't subcalass them) and get them serialized this way. But then you would still not be able to read them back without another hack (i.e. introducing a surrogate class).

I'd recommend to look for an alternative to the Java Serializable mechanism in general. It's pretty much broken by design in several ways.

Comment: It's strange that so many developers are completely fine with Java's "broken by design" Serialization.  Rolling your own serialization is a horrible solution - so many standard Java libraries / frameworks make use of Serializable - are you supposed to program a workaround for every one of them?